# Taskkill for all running processes that exist in a specific directory

Tags: windows, batch, kill, tasks

I basically want to combine the following sets of commands.  In other words I need to check to see if any executable that exists in c:\apps is running, and if any are, to kill them.  Once these commands are complete, I will do a robocopy to update files in c:\apps.  This script will be deployed with SCCM.  Because of this, I need all commands to return errorlevel 0, otherwise it will report the deployment as failed.

```
tasklist 2>NUL | find /I /N "processname.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im processname.exe
```

and

```
for /r c:\apps\ %%G in (*.exe) do taskkill /F /IM %%~nxG
```

Comment: Welcome to SU!  What's your question exactly?  What problem are you running into while trying to accomplish your stated goal?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that while an executable is called `launchme.exe`, when in memory the image name might be different. `launchme.exe` may just be a wrapper to other libraries/executables which need to be loaded before the actual UI is displayed. In other words, don't rely in the executable name alone.

Comment: Ultimately I want to be able to copy some files to the c:\apps folder.  In order to do that, the executables that exist in c:\apps all have to be killed off.  Good point on the wrappers, but in my case, it's not a concern.  Also, sidenote, the reason I want errorcode 0 is so that the deployment in SCCM won't report as "failed".

Answer (score 1):

I propose something such as:

> WMIC PROCESS WHERE "ExecutablePath like 'C:\Apps\%%'" DELETE

There's an apostrophe followed directly by quotation marks there, so you may want to just copy and paste that.

So that's just one rather simple line (rather than a batch file).

This is a fairly powerful and flexible technique.  So, if that doesn't end up working exactly like what you have in mind, play with it.  There's likely to be a property that will be unique to the programs you're seeking to kill.  An example for researching the details is available at:
[taskkill - end tasks with window titles ending with a specific string : TOOGAM's answer](http://superuser.com/a/861229/401839) which presents a fairly similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

See this batch work for you.

```
@echo off

pushd c:\apps
FOR %%A IN (*.exe) do (
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%A" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%%A">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im %%A
)
```

Comment: He included a /R  and %%~nxG and what he did there was better. /R looks through subdirectories.  and no need for a pushd if you use the for loop header that he had. And if you're going to do a pushd you might want to do a popd. And if he wants the whole thing to end in errorlevel 0, you might want to do something like `dir c:\windows >nul` at the end.